# Cant get my head around why this code works

Tags: c++

This is a basic c++ code that lets the user have 3 chances to guess a secret number.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int secretnumber(5);
    int guess;
    int guessamount(0);
    int guesslimit(3);
    bool outofguesses = false;

    while (guess != secretnumber && !outofguesses) {

        if (guessamount < guesslimit) {
            std::cout << "Enter your guess" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> guess;
            guessamount++;
        } else {
            outofguesses = true;
        }
    }
    if (!outofguesses) {
        std::cout << "Congrats, you guessed it!";

    } else {
        std::cout << "You lost";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But, I can't wrap my head around the workings of the `outofguesses` bool. In the while parameters, it states that "while `guess`'s value is not equal to `secretnumber`'s value, and while `!outofguesses`.

To me, `!` here switches the value from false to true right? So that's saying, "while `outofguesses = true`, run this loop. But wouldn't that be wrong? Shouldn't it just be `while(guess != secretnumber && outofguesses)`, since `outofguesses` was already declared false when we declared the boolean initially?

Comment: Note that `guess` is used uninitialized, anything could happen.

Comment: In that case `while` means `until`. Read it as loop until you're **not outofguesses**

Comment: While you have not found the correct value or run out of guesses, let the user take another guess.

Comment: `!outofguesses` is true when `outofguesses` is false; it is equivalent to `outofguesses == false`. Write it out in plain English: "while the guess is different from the secret and we're not out of guesses, do ...`. Makes sense, right? (I think you're thinking too much about programming and too little about what "out of guesses" means.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To me, ! here switches the value from false to true right? So that's saying, "while outofguesses = true, run this loop. But wouldn't that be wrong?

What is wrong is your interpretation. Take only this part of the condition:

```
while ( !outofguesses)
```

The loop continues as long as the condition is `true`. Because the condition is negated, the loop continues as long as `outofguesses == false`. And thats what makes sense: The game ends when the player is out of guesses. (It continues as long as the player is not out of guesses)

As mentioned in a comment, the other part of the condition `guess != secretnumber` uses `guess` uninitialized on the first iteration, hence invokes undefined behavior. Always initialize your variables!

Comment: Sorry i still don't understand what you mean, surely `!outofguesses` means true, as its declared false initially, meaning that adding the negation makes it true. If its true that the player is out of guesses, then shouldn't the loop stop? Also with the initilaization, i was under the impression that the cin >> initialises it, can you please let me know some more regarding that, thanks! :)

Comment: @Quack the loop runs "while" the condition is `true`. Compare `while ( you_did_not_understand_it ) keep_asking();` with `while ( ! you_did_understand_it ) keep_asking();`, they are doing the same, just meaning of `you_did_not_understand_it` and `you_did_understand_it` flipped

Comment: @Quak `while (! outofguesses)` does stop when the player is out of guesses, because when the player is out of guesses then `outofguesses` is `true`. `!outofguesses` is `false`. And the loop stops when the condition is `false`

Answer (score -2):

The while loop stop and go to if only when guess = secretnumber or outofguess = true, if outofguess = false, of course guess = secretnumber now and print "congrats", or else (outofguess = true) print "You lost"